# How do I loop through any enum to convert all possible values to string?

Tags: c#, string, list, methods, enums

As title says, from this enum:

```
public enum DeeMacsEnum
{
Value1,
Value2,
Value3
}
```

I would like a `List<String>`. First element will have "Value1", second will be "Value2" etc.

However, I would like to keep this method generic enough for it to iterate through any type of enum

**What I've Tried:**

```
Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DeeMacsEnum));
```

^ This works fine. But not generic. In an attempt to make it reusable I changed it to this:

```
var type = enumObject.GetType();
Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(type));
```

Doesn't work (doesn't even compile), understandably.

Comment: THe problem is here. try this. Array values = Enum.GetValues(type);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have `type`, no need to use `typeof` anymore

```
  var type = enumObject.GetType();
  Array values = Enum.GetValues(type);
```

Comment: Of course I already have the type. I feel ridiculous now. Such a simple one. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DeeMacsEnum));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
string[] s = Enum.GetNames(typeof(YourEnumType));
```

Answer (score 0):

why not try this

```
public IEnumerable<string> getEnumValues<T>() where  T: struct,IConvertible
            {
            var type = typeof(T);
            if (type.IsEnum)
                {
                return Enum.GetNames(type);
                }
            else
                {
                throw new ArgumentException("Type parameter specified is not an enum type.");
                }
            }
```